# Handlebars, avoid compiling (ignore) part of a template?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is there a way to tell the Handlebar compiler to ignore a block of template.

I know there is the `\` solution, like :

```
\{{ is.ignored}}
```

but is there something that would do the same, but for a complete block, like :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="my-template">
    <ul>
        {{#each items}}
            <li><a href="{{url}}" title="{{title}}">{{display}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

I believe it would be better (and far more readable) to have something like `{{#ignore}}{{/ignore}}` instead of adding `\` everywhere.

I tried to find something using block helpers, either building something myself, but I can't get my hand on the non-compiled version of what's inside the block.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, Cyril's answer seems out of date? I found this alternative in the [Handlebars documentation on raw blocks](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#raw-blocks):

### Raw Blocks

Raw blocks are available for templates needing to handle unprocessed mustache blocks.

```
{{{{raw-helper}}}}
    {{bar}}
{{{{/raw-helper}}}}
```

will execute the helper raw-helper without interpreting the content.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('raw-helper', function(options) {
    return options.fn();
});
```

will render

```
{{bar}}
```

Comment: Yes indeed, my answer is now invalid, so I've marked yours as good :)

Comment: Is is required to call `registerHelper` before parsing any template?

Answer (score 10):

Yes I finally found it, it's called ... `raw` ! :

```
{% raw %}
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="my-template">
    <ul>
        {{#each items}}
            <li><a href="{{url}}" title="{{title}}">{{display}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
{% endraw %}
```

Update : After an update of Handlebars, this snipped seems to not work now. I [opened a ticket](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars-site/issues/82) to see how to make it works.